# What language are best for creating data compression algorithms except for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I've been trying to implement data compression algorithms in python, but I just can't get mine as fast as the other algorithms other have made. So I've decided on using **C** since I've asked people about this and what I got was I should choose a language that is very close to hardware, however I find C very hard because of the memory stuff so I made some progress but it's very frustrating since I can't code in C well. So what are some great alternatives for this issue? I've looked into Rust, and Golang are these languages fit for data compression? what languages are there that could calculate stuff like this very fast?

Comment: Data compression is [an active area of research](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~dcc/Call.html), and your interests seem to lie in *implementation*.  Your frustration in learning C is probably compounded by setting out as a goal to get your implementation "as fast as the other algorithms other have made."  Simply switching to a different language/tool chain is not a quick fix, and I'd recommend refining the goal: what kind of data compression algorithm do you want to implement?

Comment: Why not use the opportunity to learn C/C++?

Comment: Learning C will help you understand why implementations using it are faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my general experience, the following are required in order to get "reasonable" performance from a programming language:

1. The ability to specify static types. It's OK if the language also has dynamic typing (even if that's the default), but generally using this part of the language will have significant overhead for hot code.
2. The ability to work directly with integers (i.e. don't treat every number type as a float). Bonus if you can specify the bit width of the integer type, and if the integer is unsigned/signed.
3. The ability to work with "raw" numeric values, not only with boxed wrapper classes. By this I mean not using things like `Integer` in Java, but use `int`. Languages like C# which only let you use boxed wrapper numerical values suffer a significant performance penalty when you want to perform numerical operations in hot code.

Generally this can get you most of the way to decent performance. There are of course other language features which may be required to get the absolutely best performance in all cases. These are:

1. Access to inline assembly/intrinsics
2. Some way to work with SIMD types
3. Multithread capable
4. Manual memory/resource management. This can come in the form of scopes ([RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)), or manually allocating/deleting. Generally you want to avoid doing either of these in hot code, however some efficient algorithms unfortunately may end up requiring this.

Whether these features are helpful or not are problem dependent, though fast compression libraries generally use all of these.

You also need to have access to a good optimizing compiler for your language. It's OK if the compiler compiles to an intermediate "bytecode" for filesystem storage, so long as at execution hot code is compiled into optimized machine code.

Languages which I know can get decent performance:

1. C
2. C++
3. Fortran
4. Julia
5. Java. Note: while you can write "fast" Java code, it is quite painful, much more painful than writing fast C code, and by "fast" code I mean it may be able to get within 2x of decent C code performance, sometimes even within 10%.

There may be other languages which satisfy these requirements. Some other languages which come to mind are Objective C, Go, Rust, and Swift. I know almost nothing about these languages, however I have seen benchmark results from others suggesting there is some hope for these languages.
I have no idea if any of these languages suffer from similar pitfalls of Java where good performance is theoretically possible but much more painful than others in practice.
No matter which language you choose, getting good performance will always be painful. Even if you choose C or C++ you can write code which performs worse than Python.

That all being said, I don't really understand why you want to write your own compression algorithms. There are lots of libraries available which allow you to use compression algorithms which other people have written which are already fast and well tested for correctness (correctness is more important than speed; it doesn't matter if you get the wrong answer faster).

If you just want to learn about the algorithms and methods used by some of the existing implementations, you can use almost any language and just understand that your implementation won't be as fast as theirs. If you really want to create/improve a compression algorithm for others to use, you are almost certainly going to have to learn C/C++ since many existing implementations are taking advantage of features in these two languages like inline assembly and intrinsics which very few other languages support.

Learning C/C++ is generally a good idea anyways. C++ at least can be very beginner friendly, and learning about how the syntax is structured and the general concepts presented will help you learn other languages since many other languages are derived from C/C++.

Comment: Thank for the very detailed answer, I think I am gonna try C++. But can C++ achieve the same speed as C? isn't it more complex?

Comment: C++ is explicitly designed to allow for the same speed as C. And it achieves this in practice as well if you stick to the usual idiomatic ways of programming.